# XE coverter issue with Blue Prism

Tags: google-chrome, blueprism, rpa

I'm using windows10, and Blue Prism version 6.7.

I'm still new to Blue Prism, and try to re-do an exercise using "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/" and "chrome".

My problem is that I'm not able to write into the "from" currency. I have tried multiple things and not success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say you've "tried multiple things" without success - please specify *which* things. Have you tried emulating mouse clicks? Send Keys? Global Send Keys?

Comment: You should also be aware the linked site's Terms of Service prohibit automation against their service: "*use any automatic or manual process to[...] systematically extract data or data fields, including without limitation any financial and/or currency data[...]*"

Comment: Hi @esqew, I used the site for testing purpose. For future occurrence I will take care of this. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm if you have followed the below approaches to write the data in "From" textbox:

1) Using Write stage to write the value

2) Using send keys to reach to the text box and then typing using GSK

3) Were you able to spy the "From" textbox using Browser mode? If not, did you try using Application Navigator to take the whole HTML page and then try spying the textbox?

4) If none of the approaches worked, did you try using Surface automation technique?

Comment: Thank you Manpreet, It worked using GSK and by adding wait and navigate stage before  write stage.